# I'm trying to use sed as a replacement for grep

Tags: shell, unix, sed, ksh

The command I'm trying to use is

```
sed -n 's/'$LASTNAME'/pgIw '$TEMP_FILE2'' < "$TEMP_FILE"
```

My goal is to get search TEMP_FILE for the value in LASTNAME and write the line containing the match, if there is one, it to TEMP_FILE2. I keep getting that the sed command is garbled. The code above will return

```
sed: command garbled: s/smith/pgIw /tmp/tmp.aKaGFH
```

Any help is appreciated! I've been trying to figure this out for hours! This is suppose to be done in the Korn shell in UNIX and I can't use awk or python, it is the stipulations of the homework.

Thank you!

Comment: The s command means substitution. Greg Hewgill's answer clears that up.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have an abundance of quotes that you don't need. Try:

```
sed -n "/$LASTNAME/p" >$TEMP_FILE2 <$TEMP_FILE
```

Also, your use of the `s` sed command seems to be out of place, since you don't actually want to substitute anything.

Comment: Thank you. Can I use the g and I flags at the end at least to search the file globally and to make the search case insensitive?

Comment: Also, when I just ran it after changing it to:

     sed -n "/$LASTNAME/pgI" >$TEMP_FILE2  <$TEMP_FILE

It comes back with

sed: command garbled: /smith/pgI

Comment: edit your question to show what value you are using for LASTNAME. `g` may be your problem, as it only applies to global (per line matched) substitutions. Think about it, `s/x/y/` will only replace 1 `x` with 1 `y`, while `s/x/y/g` will sub a `y` for each instance of `x` on the line that currently matches the search target, i.e. `x`. Good luck.

Comment: I just tried what you suggested shellter and I'm getting the same "sed: command garbled: /smith/pI"

Comment: Does it work if you omit the `I`? Because that's not valid after a `p` command.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to find something and pipe to output, then simply use grep

```
grep -i "$LASTNAME" "$TEMP_FILE" > "$TEMP_FILE2"  # -i case-insensitive
```

Or Perl

```
perl -ne "print if /$LAST_NAME/" "$TEMP_FILE" > "$TEMP_FILE2"
```

Comment: I also can't use perl. I'm trying to make the search case insensitive.

Comment: use -i option from grep

Comment: Just tried that but it is telling me that it cannot open TEMP_FILE which I think was happening before.

Comment: @Airforcefalco: Can you try: `grep -i "$LASTNAME" "$TEMP_FILE" > "/tmp/$TEMP_FILE2"`

Comment: TEMP_FILE is your variable name. When you want to use variable, you put "$" in front.